# Font size changes in inline math equation

Tags: math-mode

I want my (pic 1) inline math equation to be of the same size as of everything else.  Pic 2 is a snap from a book. and pic 2 looks better . How to have inline math equation to be of the same size .  [image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried `\dfrac`? But watch out for the interline spacing... Note that it is in general bigger in your pic2. Also, In your pic1, the text and math fonts do not really match (that is a bigger issue than the size of the fraction, which probably looks best slashed anyways). Again, welcome!

Comment: The whole point of inline math is to avoid disturbing the line spacing. If you use `\dfrac` as in the second image you will get irregular spacing which many publishers would not find acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @mickep. can you please guide me how to make math fonts and text as same font ? thanks again.

Comment: Are you ok with using inline-fraction notation for derivatives? If so, consider writing `$d\vec{r}/ds$` instead of `$\frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}$`.